# Query to Salesforce using Jsforce nodejs package loads infinitely leading to a request abortion

Tags: node.js, express, salesforce, salesforce-lightning, jsforce

I'm trying to fetch data from salesforce using [jsforce](https://jsforce.github.io/) npm package but the request just keeps loading. I'm using the [Username and Password Login (OAuth2 Resource Owner Password Credential)](https://jsforce.github.io/document/#username-and-password-login-oauth2-resource-owner-password-credential-) auth method; the authentication flow returns the access_token and instance url but the actual query loads infinitely.

Here is the simple nodejs app code I've tried

```
import express from 'express';
import jsforce from 'jsforce';
import dotenv from 'dotenv';
dotenv.config();

const app = express();
const port = 3000;

let conn = new jsforce.Connection({
    oauth2 : {
        clientId: process.env.SF_CLIENT_ID,
        clientSecret: process.env.SF_CLIENT_SECRET,
        redirectUri: process.env.SF_REDIRECT_URI,
        loginUrl: process.env.SF_LOGIN_URL
    },
    loginUrl : process.env.SF_LOGIN_URL
});

conn.login(process.env.SF_USERNAME, process.env.SF_PASSWORD, (err, userInfo) => {
    if (err) {
        return console.error("This error is from the login attempt: ", err);
    }
    console.log(`Access Token: ${conn.accessToken}`);
    console.log(`Instance URL: ${conn.instanceUrl}`);
    console.log(`User ID: ${userInfo.id}`);
    console.log(`Org ID: ${userInfo.organizationId}`);
});

app.get('/cases', (req, res) => {
    conn.query("SELECT Id, CaseNumber FROM Case", (err, result) => {
        if (err) {
            return console.error(err);
        }
        console.log(`total : ${result.totalSize}`);
        console.log(`fetched : ${result.records.length}`);
        res.send(result.records);
    });
});

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`App listening at http://localhost:${port}`);
});
```

I was expecting the the `/cases` endpoint to return the list of cases when I send a request to http://localhost:3000

Comment: hey. did you ever figure this out? if you log "result" right away in the callback, do you see anything? or does that conn.query call just never come back?